# Can not open a file with opencv predefined class FileStorage

Tags: opencv, visual-studio-2013, yaml

I am using visual Studio 2013 and working on Windows 8.1. As far as a controlled I am passing the path correctly. But it doesn't open or assess the file.

```
int main()
{
    ft_data data = load_ft<ft_data>("D:\\MasterThesesInfo\\DatasetFacesz\\uncompressed\\anotations&jpg\\MacLabels.yaml");
    //And so on , does  matter
}
```

This is my struct:

```
template <class T>
T load_ft(const char* fname){
    T x; FileStorage f(fname, FileStorage::READ);
    f["ft object"] >> x; f.release(); return x;
} template<class T>

// Also have tried this way
template <class T>
T load_ft(const char* fname){
    T x;
    FileStorage f;
    f.open(fname, FileStorage::READ);
    if (!f.isOpened())
    {
        cout << "Could not open the configuration file: \"" << endl;

    }
    f["name"] >> x;
    FileStorage ff = f;
    f.release(); return x;
}
```

Comment: What's `ft_data `? Have you tried without all this template stuff?

Comment: I think in my case it doesnt matter, because it enters the load_ft function. and fails to open the file, and the filename is a string which is passed correctly

Comment: Have you tried a path without the "&" ? Maybe that's causing the problem

Comment: I have created an empty .yml file with notepad in another location. And it cant be  opened as well. :(